# SMB2 opens for Query Directory requests

Tags: winapi, filesystems, smb, cifs

Is there a way to definitely identify whether an open request sent by SMB2 client is for reading a file or enumerating the directory(SMB2 query directory request)? Sometimes, the requests are compounded and in some cases they are not. Does any flag in the open request indicate that the open which the client is attempting to do is to read the contents of the directory and not the file?

I know that the create option flag cannot be relied upon for this as few clients may ignore to set that flag.

Comment: I'm probably overlooking something, but doesn't the request contain a path?  Which either refers to a file or to a directory?

Comment: Yes. The request contains the path, but without resolving the path, we will not be able to determine if its a file or not. I want to avoid this step of resolving the path to determine if the request refers to a file or directory.

Comment: A Windows programmer can make a file open request that is valid against either a file or a directory, and can be used for either purpose.  I would *guess* that in this case, at least, the request would be passed to the server without the client even knowing whether the target was a file or directory.

Comment: Microsoft should have set some flag to clearly indicate in OPEN request that the current open op would be on a file or a directory (i.e: one of the MUST to be set flags) .